Specifying a KexAlgorithms algorithm in sshd_config to mitigate Terrapin
Do I need to directly specify kex-strict-s-v00@openssh.com under KexAlgorithms in sshd_config or does the "pseudo" KEX take effect anyway?
I can't see clarity in the sshd docs.
From what I see, if I only specify curve25519, I still see the v00@openssh.com KEX appended in the logs:
debug2: KEX algorithms: curve25519-sha256,kex-strict-s-v00@openssh.com
So this would indicate one doesn't manually specify?

It's not an algorithm or even a pseudo-algorithm; only an indicator that has been stuffed into the same list as algorithm names for lack of any better place. The presence of the indicator is enough for it to have an effect – in fact the names have been specifically chosen so that they could never possibly be chosen as an "algorithm" by the handshake process (only the server advertises -s- and only the client advertises -c- indicators), meaning that their priority within the list does not matter.

Thanks, do I need to specify it in sshd_config to be protected or is it automatic?

It's an always active feature, and you already saw that it was automatically sent without being configured, so there would be no change if you configured it manually. Again, it's not meant to be considered a kex algorithm in any way; it only happens to be sent as one, but it specifically doesn't fall under kex configuration.

Thank you for your insight!
